# /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or dirctory

Tags: ros, setup.bash, raspberrypi, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS on raspberry pi 2 model b. The ubuntu-mate 16.04 OS is installed. During environment setup I am getting /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or dirctory error.

Whats the solution?

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253298//opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash:-no-such-file-or-dirctory/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-30**:
Are you sure the earlier commands completed successfully? If you don't have that file, I fear that you haven't installed ROS at all.

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2017-01-31**:
Well I tried to install it again everything from start, there was problem in installing rosdep then i followed #q32875 this page but I again i faced same problem during environment setup.

Can I install Indigo ROS on ubuntu-mate 16.04??

**Comment by [S_Lzrnk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29212/s_lzrnk/) on 2017-01-31**:
Indigo officially does't Ubuntu 16.04
[link text](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#indigo-igloo-may-2014)
Kinectic works fine on Raspberry Pi with Mate 16.04

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-31**:
As @S_Lzrnk mentions, Indigo is not supported on 16.04, but Kinetic should be. I'm not sure about RPi2 binary builds though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI... I got the solution. If you use the command

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

this will solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) with karma: 88 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [1at7](https://answers.ros.org/users/44428/1at7/) on 2019-08-02**:
not fixing the problem for me for same error